# How to fix AWS EC2 Nginx 502 Bad Gateway issue caused after rebooting the server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

I have a Python/Flask backend with several Rest APIs. I deployed the program in the AWS EC2 instance. **APIs were worked just fine previously** and for a moment, I stopped the instance and started it again (without doing a single bit of a change). **The problem is, now all the APIs are throwing 502 Bad Gateway Error.** How can I fix this?

**Now APIs are working when I manually run the python file** using

```
python3 main.py
```

and it is running on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` on the instance console.

**So it seems like the Nginx is not listening to the Flask server, but not sure!**

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
 location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

***I tried copying the above default file to the sites-enabled as well**. Still not working

netstat -tunlp

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 172.31.37.30:68         0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

/var/log/nginx/access.log

```
43.250.243.234 - - [26/Mar/2022:21:07:20 +0000] "GET /islive?videoUrl=https://smart-cap.obs.ap-southeast-3.myhuaweicloud.com/1648198646232_1648198646232.webm HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.83 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: What do you see in ngnix error logs?

Comment: How did you setup automatic start of your flask app after a reboot? Using systemd unit files?

Comment: @Riz Thats the last part (/var/log/nginx/access.log) in the question

Comment: @Marcin Didn't do such a thing... just stopped and started after couple of minutes

Comment: @DavidJohns, these are the errors you see in the access logs but if there is some issue on the application level, you need to check the error logs. Maybe some issues with permissions/selinux?

Answer (score 1):

Could be due to the service is down.
Eg, if your service name is test-application, then run the below. Worked for me.

**sudo service test-application restart**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the service file I created to auto-run the Application. I accidentally added the wrong username for the username field. If anyone got this issue, please check if you have put the correct username in all the relevant places.